Visual Studio console outputting wrong characters
I am working on a project using the characters ▓ and ░. Currently, I have code that looks like this:
const char dark = 0xB2;
const char light = 0xB0;
cout << dark;
cout << light;

This code works perfectly fine and outputs the correct characters on my laptop and my alternate desktop, but on my main desktop this code outputs the characters ー instead of the light shade and ｲ instead of the dark shade.
I assume I am using the wrong character set or other setting in Visual Studio somehow, but this is a fresh install and I haven't touched anything like that, and like I said it works fine on my two other PCs.

I'm confident the problem is one of encoding.  On my system, ▓ is "\xE2\x96\x93" and ░ is "\xE2\x96\x91".  The bad news is that (more-or-less) C++ doesn't care.  If any part of the I/O disagrees as to the encoding, the result is likely mojibake (garbled or gibberish text that is the result of text being decoded using an unintended character encoding).

As far as I know, Visual Studio does not have a built-in console. Do you mean Visual Studio Code, an entirely different and unrelated product?

Whatever the output box is that pops up when you press the green arrow in visual studio.

You are using char values that are outside of the basic ASCII set (0-127), so their interpretation and display are very much dependent on the particular charset which the console is configured to use.
For instance, the IBM850 charset (codepage 850) has the characters you are interested in, whereas charset JIS_X0201 (codepage 50222) outputs the other characters you mention for the same char values.
If you need to use a specific charset for your output, try using SetConsoleOutputCP().

Adding this to my program only causes errors that prevent it from compiling entirely. Is it written in C instead of C++? Is there a version for C++?

@Luke Baco  Try #include<Windows.h> ....int main(){ SetConsoleOutputCP(850)....//Your console current code page is Japanese 10001. screenshot

The character encoding for my pc was incorrect.
I did this and it fixed the issue:
https://scholarslab.github.io/learn-twarc/08-win-region-settings

Changing the region settings for the whole OS just to make one app behave is not a good solution. Also, the particular setting you changed isn't even the best way to enable the UTF-8 feature, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/globalizing/use-utf8-code-page Also, the code you showed requires updating to output UTF-8 strings. Also see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/utf-8-set-source-and-executable-character-sets-to-utf-8. Also, there are MANY questions on StackOverflow related to outputting Unicode strings.

I was simply stating what fixed my issue. I spent a while trying other solutions from this website and this is the only one that worked.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Even if changing the local regional settings, your program may have the same problem on other computers. As the region of each computer may not the same. Consider editing the console region in code: SetConsoleOutputCP().
